# VBA code to select certain worksheets in Excel and save as new workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Is it possible to use VBA in order to select certain worksheets in an Excel workbook and save as new workbook file?

Comment: Guy, please let me know if the VBA code below is what you were looking for or if you need directions in executing it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, here is a sample.

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Sheets("Sheet1").Copy      
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook      
  With wb
    .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Workbookname.xlsx"
    '.Close False
  End With
End Sub
```

<sup>[Source](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?34574-Solved-Save-sheet-to-new-workbook)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Petr. I managed to hack together the code below by recording myself and Googling the rest as I needed to save several workbooks from the one and automatically add the date. It seems to be working.

```
Sub Seperate_Sheets()

Dim Path1 As String
Dim Path2 As String
Dim Path3 As String

Path1 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Tracker 1" & Format(Now, " dd-mm-yyyy ")
Path2 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Tracker 2" & Format(Now, " dd-mm-yyyy ")
Path3 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Tracker 3" & Format(Now, " dd-mm-yyyy ")

Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")).Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets(Array("sheet3", "sheet4", "sheet5")).Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path2, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close

Sheets(Array("sheet6", "sheet7", "sheet8")).Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path3, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it's working. If you'll have to do many of these then looping (e.g., for loop) might be of great help in the future.